# Get unread notifications of a stackexchange user

Tags: stackexchange-api

I came across [StackExchange API V2 unread notifications](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-unread-notifications)  method and though of creating a small  cli script which on execution will give me the unread notification count. Now, according to the docs this method requires authentication`(access token)` to fetch the data.

After reading [authentication docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) I found that one needs certain parameters like `client_id` to complete the  `implicit OAuth 2.0 flow`.

I tried registering app at `stackapps.com` but it requires `OAuth Domain, Application Website` which I don't have.

So, what is the simplest way to get `access_token` to read users inbox for unread notification count.

Answer (score 0):

Below is dirty one but you can try it

Say you have registered application at stackOverflow , With some dummy OAuth Domain = **abc.com**

- Hit GET request :

  https://stackexchange.com/oauth?client_id=**YR_CLIENT_ID**&scope=**no_expiry,read_inbox,private_info**&redirect_uri=**YR_REDIRECT_URL**

where YR_REDIRECT_URL will be like http://myurl.abc.com

- It will redirect to URL like below with some code.

  **YR_REDIRECT_URL**/?code=**SOME_CODE**
- Get the code from redirected URL and form the POST request

  https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=**YR_CLIENT_ID**&scope=no_expiry,read_inbox,private_info&redirect_uri=**YR_REDIRECT_URL**&client_secret=**YR_CLIENT_SECRET**&code=**SOME_CODE**
- Then you will get response like below

  access_token=**YR_ACCESS_TOKEN**

You can use generated access_token(along with application key) with no_expiry (as generated with **scope=no_expiry**)